# onEdit Timestamp offset for range pasted programmatically from script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am creating a tool in which I have a column of drop downs containing a list of products. When a product is selected in the drop down list I am using the following code to add a timestamp to an adjacent column, 12 cols offset from the column being edited.

```js
  function RequestTime(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = s.getName();
  var ar = e.range;
  var row = ar.getRow();
  var arRows = ar.getNumRows()  
  if( ar.getColumn() == 4 && sName == 'Product Requests') { 
      s.getRange(row,15,arRows).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
 }
```

It works great when editing cells individually, or even a range of cells. However, on another sheet I have an auxiliary tool, which generates a list of products to request, and am using a separate script to "request" in mass, a list of products, which pastes in the lastrow +1 of Col D.

```js
function SubmitReplenAudit() {
//This next group of code will move the requests to the product request tab
//Select the column we will check for the first blank cell
  var confirmedVals = request.getRange("D1:D").getValues();
  var confirmedLast = confirmedVals.filter(String).length;
  var destRange = request.getRange(confirmedLast+2,4);

//Copy and paste name in reference column to request sheet
  var source1 = source.getRange(6,16,source.getLastRow(),1)
  source1.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

However when I run this script, the timestamp only gets added to the first offset row of the range being copied. I would like the timestamp to get added to all rows of the range being copied. After doing some research it does not appear like onEdit can be triggered with a script. So I am looking for alternatives here. I need to maintain the ability to have the time stamp trigger when edited by a user, AND add timestamps when triggered by a script.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Yes my issue is that I have an onEdit script (top) that adds a time stamp to an offset column. It is working as intended EXCEPT for when I paste in values using a separate script (bottom). I am looking for a way to add timestamps both when a user edit triggers the top script, OR when I run the bottom script. The onEdit function does not work when I am pasting values using the bottom script. Thanks

Comment: onEdit triggers only fire for user edits not for changes which originate from other scripts.  So your code is working correctly.

Comment: @Cooper is it possible to add any code to the bottom script that can work as an alternative to the onEdit? i.e. some combo of offset/setvalues?

Comment: You could have the script that makes the edits also add the time stamps

Comment: I would like to go with that, where I am struggling is creating the code to do this. How do I go about creating a one-dimensional array of timestamps the same length as source1 array?

Comment: I'd guess one row at a time

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the end of your function:

```
request.getRange(confirmedLast+2,15,source1.length,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
```